# Getting a 403 Forbidden error on GREG Console (wso2greg-5.4.0)

Tags: authentication, console, wso2

I just downloaded wso2greg-5.4.0 and can login to the store and publisher with no issue using the default admin/admin, but when I do the same for the console it gives me a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: What is the JDK version you are using?

Comment: Also do you see any errors on Console?